# What's the difference between the fields "owshiddenversion" and "OData__UIVersion"?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

Query is something like `.../_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items?$select=File,File/ServerRelativeUrl,OData__UIVersion,owshiddenversion,FileRef`

This worked in a SP Root site: `OData__UIVersion` was the exact number of versions.

But in a subsite (the same SP), for a file with just **one** version, `OData__UIVersion` is ***512***...

Next, I discovered the other field: `owshiddenversion`; This one seems to really return the correct value: ***the number of versions of a file***.

Does anybody know what's the *official* definition of these 2 fields ?
Is it safe to rely on `owshiddenversion` to determine how many versions a file has ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.microsoft.com/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-listsws/65c0df83-47b8-4b0e-a195-2a6c22a4cfe8 , owshiddenversion is used for conflict detection, and according to https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-wssfo/20d052c8-4aa6-452d-bef4-2713578a74f2 , _UIVersion is the version number.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the official documentation at:

[2.2.7.3 AllUserData Table](https://docs.microsoft.com/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-wssfo/20d052c8-4aa6-452d-bef4-2713578a74f2)

[3.1.4.31.2.1 UpdateListItems](https://docs.microsoft.com/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-listsws/65c0df83-47b8-4b0e-a195-2a6c22a4cfe8)